# Connecting to a java socket using a domain name and no port

Tags: java

I am trying to connect to my own server socket using only a domain name. I own the domain and have set up a subdomain that goes to the Server Socket's ip and the port. How would I only use the domain name in the Socket constructor to connect to the server socket? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't connect a socket with no port. When you connect with a protocol and don't specify a port (in a web browser for example `http://yourweb.com`) the port is inferred by the protocol http=80. If you are port forwarding to a sub domain, which I'm guessing is what you describe, there is always a port for the incoming connections ie. `http://yourweb.com:80 -> http://sub.yourweb.com:8080`.

Comment: Thank you! I do not know why I did not think of this. Have a great day!